# Why is local memory in this OpenCL algorithm so slow?

Tags: performance, memory, opencl, local

I am writing some OpenCL code. My kernel should create a special "accumulator" output based on an input image. I have tried two concepts and both are equally slow, although the second one uses local memory. Could you please help me identify why the local memory version is so slow? The target GPU for the kernels is a AMD Radeon Pro 450.

```
// version one
__kernel void find_points(__global const unsigned char* input, __global unsigned int* output) {
  const unsigned int x = get_global_id(0);
  const unsigned int y = get_global_id(1);

  int ind;

  for(k = SOME_BEGINNING; k <= SOME_END; k++) {
    // some pretty wild calculation
    // ind is not linear and accesses different areas of the output
    ind = ...
    if(input[y * WIDTH + x] == 255) {
      atomic_inc(&output[ind]);
    }
  }

}

// variant two
__kernel void find_points(__global const unsigned char* input, __global unsigned int* output) {
  const unsigned int x = get_global_id(0);
  const unsigned int y = get_global_id(1);

  __local int buf[7072];
  if(y < 221 && x < 32) {
    buf[y * 32 + x] = 0;
  }
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

  int ind;
  int k;

  for(k = SOME_BEGINNING; k <= SOME_END; k++) {
    // some pretty wild calculation
    // ind is not linear and access different areas of the output
    ind = ...
    if(input[y * WIDTH + x] == 255) {
      atomic_inc(&buf[ind]);
    }
  }

  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
  if(get_local_id(0) == get_local_size(0) - 1)
    for(k = 0; k < 7072; k++)
      output[k] = buf[k];
  }

}
```

I would expect that the second variant is faster than the first one, but it isn't. Sometimes it is even slower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local buffer size `__local int buf[7072]` (28288 bytes) is too big. I don't know how big shared memory for AMD Radeon Pro 450 is but likely that is 32kB or 64kB per computing unit.

`32768/28288 = 1`, `65536/28288 = 2` means only 1 or maximum 2 wavefronts (64 work items) can run simultaneously only, so occupancy of computing unit is very very low hence poor performance.

Your aim should be to reduce local buffer as much as possible so that more wavefronts can be processed simultaneously.

Use `CodeXL` to profile your kernel - there are tools to show you all of this.
Alternatively you can have a look at `CUDA occupancy calculator` excel spreadsheet if you don't want to run the profiler to get a better idea of what that is about.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fast reply. I have an understandance question: if I set my local work size in OpenCL to 64 and my global working size is 128, then I have 20 work groups. 64 is also the number of threads in a wavefront. So I will have 20 wavefronts. If I have one computing unit of 4 SIMDs with 16 ALUs then I can parse no more than one wavefront per CU. And local memory is per CU, not per wavefront. So even if I work on 2 half-wavefronts simultaneously, I will still work on one and the same local buffer. Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: Local buffer (OpenCL term) is per workgroup, not per CU. On GPU local buffer is stored in shared memory which is per CU. I think more workgroups can run simultaneously on one CU if they can fit (limited by shared memory size and number of registers), so if say your local buffer is 8192 bytes and shared memory is 32768 bytes, then 5 workgroups can potentially run simultaneously on one CU. Then if there is 5 CUs on GPU then all 20 worgroups could run simultaneously. That's probably explained somewhere in the architecture docs.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of local memory issues, the second variant only has one thread of the workgroup writing to *global* memory.  Something along these lines should be faster:

```
for(k = get_local_id(0); k < 7072; k+=get_local_size(0)) {
    output[k] = buf[k];
}
```

A longer, more confusing discussion of this issue can be found here: https://community.amd.com/t5/archives-discussions/fastest-way-to-copy-from-global-memory-to-local-memory/td-p/117265